# Reuse std::cin after eating an EOF

Tags: c++, io, stdin, cin, istream

The unix command `wc` has this functionality:

```
$ wc - - -
aaa bbb ccc<EOF>
0 3 11 -
aaa bbb ccc<EOF>
0 3 11 -
aaa bbb ccc<EOF>
0 3 11 -
0 9 33 total
```

Each `<EOF>` indicates a `<C-d>` key sequence that enters an `EOF` into stdin. wc is then able to pick up this `EOF`.

I'm trying to implement this in C++. A common suggestion is  combination of `clear()` and `ignore()`.

```
char c;
while (std::cin >> c) { ... }

std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore();

while (std::cin >> c) { /* never executed */ }
```

I've also tried `std::cin.peekg(std::cin.beg)`, which also does not work.

Comment: Once you EOF `cin`, I don't think you can bring it back. If you can, it's through some arcane black arts. Better to use a different terminating condition for the loop and not kill `cin`.

Comment: This is strange. On what OS and shell could you do this. I tried to reproduce with `wc - - <<EOF` and input `a b c` and `EOF`. I got `1 3 6 -`, `0 0 0 -`, `1 3 6 total`. (I'm on `cygwin64` in Windows 10 and use `bash`.)

Comment: Btw. Before I tried to reproduce, I looked into some sources of `wc` e.g. [`wc.c`](https://github.com/wertarbyte/coreutils/blob/master/src/wc.c) to find something like "the trick" but I couldn't find anything suspicious or surprising. (And, hence I had wondered if I had got anything else...)

Comment: @Scheff  I can reproduce this on Ubuntu subsystem of Windows and Arch Linux.

Comment: Yeah, cygwin is at best a sub-optimal replacement for Linux. I only use it because I cannot without `find` and `grep` but mis-trust the new fancy Linux sub-systems offered in Windows.

Comment: You could download one of the sources of wc.c, compile it in debug mode, and "spy" how they do. If you don't find anything specific then my next assumption would be something in `libc` or the OS itself. This behavior surprises me...

Comment: @Scheff: Of course `wc` has no special code: that’s what you get if you open `/dev/stdin` repeatedly (when it’s the terminal) and read it until EOF.

Comment: @DavisHerring That's precisely what confuses me. If I got it right nothing in `wc` opens `/dev/stdin` (or did I miss something). It's just the `-` arg. which uses `stdin` instead of `f = fopen(...);` So, "re-opening `/dev/stdin`" should be provided from outside. I doubt that the shell somehow interpretes the `- - -` after `wc`. So, something is missing in my head to bring this together...

Comment: @DavisHerring If you could explain this I recommend to write an answer. I guess it's worth at least two upvotes as I would like to know as well how this can work. ;-)

Comment: @Scheff: I want to test something before answering, but I *can* explain that the behavior with a here-document (`<<EOF`) is quite separate because it doesn’t involve a terminal.

Comment: @DavidHerring The user didn't use a here-doc. - he just typed `^D` but I did. Is this _the_ difference? It seems so. (Now, I can reproduce in cygwin. Oops.) So, does this mean that the shell (or the terminal) closes and re-opens `/dev/stdin` on `^D` (but not for here-docs)?

Comment: @DavidHerring Thank's for the enlightment. I found [What's the difference between ^C and ^D for UNIX/Mac OS X terminal?](https://superuser.com/a/169057) (Please, note the upvoted comment under the linked answer, also.) But, I'm still wondering that this doesn't work for here-docs. Is there another trick I miss?

Answer (score 1):

With the patient help of Davis, I learned the difference between typed input finished with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and a here document which I was not aware of.  (My tribute to Davis Herring.)

Once, I got it the rest in C++ was quite simple like shown in my [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

`line-count.cc`:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

unsigned process(const std::string &fileName, std::istream &in)
{
  unsigned nLines = 0;
  if (in.bad()) {
    std::cerr << "ERROR: Cannot open '" << fileName << "'!\n";
    return 0;
  }
  for (std::string buffer; std::getline(in, buffer); ++nLines);
  std::cout << "File: '" << fileName << "', " << nLines << " counted.\n";
  return nLines;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  unsigned nLines = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
    const std::string arg = argv[i];
    if (arg == "-") {
      nLines += process(arg, std::cin);
      std::cin.clear();
    } else {
      std::ifstream fIn(arg.c_str());
      nLines += process(arg, fIn);
    }
  }
  std::cout << "Total: " << nLines << " counted.\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled and tested in [cygwin64](http://www.cygwin.org):

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -o line-count line-count.cc

$ ./line-count line-count.cc - line-count.cc -
File: 'line-count.cc', 32 counted.
1
2
3
File: '-', 3 counted.
File: 'line-count.cc', 32 counted.
1
2
3
File: '-', 3 counted.
Total: 70 counted.

$
```

So, it's indeed the trick with [`std::cin.clear()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) which resets the EOF flag in input stream and makes it possible to read again from the `/dev/stdin`.

In the case of OP, the [`std::cin.ignore()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) after `std::cin.clear()` is IMHO wrong. It discards the first character of the re-enabled standard input which makes the following processing wrong (by not counting the first character).

Davis (again) prodived a short but obvious explanation which I give in my words:

With <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, the standard input receives an EOF in the next attempt to read; and memorizes it in its internal flags. Nevertheless, the flag can be reset. If there isn't any further input the next read attempt would fail but otherwise, the input can just be continued.

May be, it's worth to emphasize the internal EOF flag in `std::ios`. Without [`std::cin.clear()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear), the read attempt would fail even when more input is available. As long as the internal `std::stream` flags doesn't result in good state, no read attempt will be performed on lower level even though it might succeed.

Comment: `clear` doesn’t *reopen* standard input; it just forgets the EOF it saw so that the next read consults the kernel again.  The kernel gives you only one EOF per ^D (or none at all if the last character was neither ^D or newline).

Comment: @DavisHerring I agree. I fixed the bottom of text slightly according to your comment.