# How to interrupt cin input while(cin >> num)?

Tags: c++

I want to interrupt inputing num   **while(cin >> num)**;.

When i input **ctrl+D** interrupt input, the program will print **input a: eof flag**.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num;
    while(1) {
        while(cin >> num);

        if (cin.eof()) {
            cout <<"eof flag" << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max());
        }
        if (cin.fail()) {
            cout <<"fail flag" << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max());
        }
        cout <<"input a: ";
        int a;
        cin >> a;
    }
}
```

The cin stream always seems to have EOF. Why happens that?

Comment: Because once the stream fails, you need to clear it.

Comment: i add a fail check. But it still print input a: eof flag.@＿Static＿assert

Comment: FYI: [SO: Reuse std::cin after eating an EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52387721/7478597)